# geometry_generator not working properly in QGIS Print Composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, geometry-generator

I'm working with QGIS 3.34 and trying so draw some lines with a given distance via the geometry_generator:

1. The Pagesize ist 297x1399 mm
2. I draw a shape (rectangle) with Length and Height via @layout_pagewidth and @layout_pageheight and with the x- and y-position of 0
3. The style is a LineString/MultiLineString (geometry_generator marker). The code looks like this:

```
collect_geometries( 
    array_foreach( generate_series(1,8) ,
        make_line(
            make_point(@element * 200,0),
            make_point(@element * 200, @layout_pageheight)
        
        )
    )
)
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

4. After this I add a map to the canvas, sadly the lines are now not being drawn correctly:

[image]

5. If I delete the map, the lines are now drawn correctly again

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you using map units or mm?

Comment: hi, units for the geomety_generator are in mm